# Dependency Injection and serialized classes

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'll just get right into it.  I have a class `User` that needs to do some DB operations (using the class `DB`).  The controllers create `DB` as appropriate, and inject it into `User` with its constructor.

When a user is logged in, a `User` object is stored to  the session.  The problem is that `DB` cannot be serialized to the session, so when `User` wakes up, its `db` member is `null`, which is bad.  I solved this pretty simply with

```
public function __wakeup() { $this->db = new DB; }
```

..however, this is definitely a violation of DI, and it could even cause problems down the line if the `DB` needs to be different depending on the controller (the controller creates the `DB` it needs, after all).

Problem is that when `User` is unserialized from the session, it's not constructed again, so it doesn't have a chance to get the DB member.  I have several possible solutions, and the problems each has:

- Allow DB to be set by setter injection

  - This also doesn't seem like a great solution.  It also opens up the possibility of setting the `DB` at an inappropriate time, and still seems to violate the DI spirit.  The controller also has to know to set the `DB`
- Don't serialize the object, but serialize a token and recreate the object every time

  - This would be inconvenient and seems inefficient.  This could also lead to some repetition (each controller would need to do something like `$usr = new User($_SESSION['user-token'], new DB);`).  On the other hand, keeping the `User` object out of superglobals would dissuade some nasty global variable usage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your user object has a dependency of the DB object and the DB object can not be serialized, your user object itself can't be serialized either.

So basically your problem is that you serialize an object that is not serialize-able.

What you actually need is session state. Create a session state object that is able to pick models (set) and which is able to provide models (get).

By adding the logic to the session object how a specific object can be serialized (or better: stored in session, e.g. you normally only need to store the ID if it's a database model) this will work like any other factory.

Then inject the Session object as a dependency.

Comment: Inject the session object into what?

Comment: Into all objects that need session state (naturally).

Comment: So the Session object gets serialized with the user ID (and some other information to specify that it is a user ID), and has a methods for recreating objects based on this?  So the `recreateUser()` method would require the controller to inject a `DB` for the recreated user to use?

Comment: Serialization first of all only means you bring an object into some other representation, e.g. to store it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization - As PHP is not able to serialize the user object (as you wrote, DB is not serializeable but it's a private member), you can't do this with build-in PHP functions. So you need to write your own serialization layer. Ideally in your case, that's the session object which represents session state. It will take care to build the models that are allowed to store inside the session at runtime then.

Comment: Take note that this is independent to the user object itself. So the user object does not have a `recreate` function at all. It's just the session object you can ask for the user, like `$session->getUser()`.

Comment: `session->getUser()` will return a `User` using something like `$_SESSION['user-token']` to create it.  Fine, but `User` has to have a valid `DB` in its constructor, and that can vary per controller.  How does the `Sesssion` object get that?

Comment: No, `$session->getUser()` will return a `User` that represents the user that is associated with the session. E.g. it builds the `user` for the stored ID. It does so by calling the appropriate factory for user. The factory does know how to construct the user incl. all it's dependencies. So pass the factories as dependency to the session object. Then it can just do the work. Make things to ask for what they need, do not search for things.

Comment: @ShalomSam: What are you looking for specifically?

Comment: @hakre so in my case there is no $session object, but i have a Cache Class that caches content to file. And in case of objects .. the objects are serialized and then cached to file. But i have hit a brick wall as to how to get the dependencies of these objects injected on unserialize. Here dependencies are stored/registered as services in a DIC.